# How can I chain together bash expect scripts?

Tags: linux, bash, expect

folks. I'm working on automating a process at work that involves entering in endless commands across a variety of VMs. It's all very simple stuff, but it's time consuming and human-error prone.

I stumbled across the "expect" commands and they suited my needs to begin with. I have a script that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh root@[server name]
expect "such and such" 
send "thing\n"
```

This repeats for a bit, and eventually I finish with the work on that VM. What I'd like the script to do is enter an exit command, and then start doing other commands in the local terminal I'm working on, like so:

```
... 
expect "last part"
send "exit\n"

expect "something"
send "new commands"
```

Alternatively:

```
...
expect "last part"
send "exit\n"

spawn ./newscript.sh
```

For whatever reason, expect seems to ignore my last `exit` command. If there's a way to do multiple spawns in one expect script, or, if there's a way to chain scripts together, please let me know.

Comment: Does newscript need to be interactive, or is it just a script that needs to run?

Comment: Just another script that needs to run. Ideally none of the scripts will require input from the user, all values will be in the script themselves.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "bash expect script". Expect scripts are written in TCL, a completely separate language from bash.

Comment: Take a look at my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write Expect scripts with **shell code only**. It supports multiple spawns very well.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
expect "last part"
send "exit\r"
expect eof    ;# allow the spawned process to gracefully exit

system ./newscript.sh
```

From the expect manual:

> `system` *args*
>
> > gives  *args*  to  sh(1)  as  input,  just as if it had been typed as a command from a terminal.  Expect waits until the shell terminates.